# Invert chars inside string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm taking care of some other methods and I don't know what to do with this one. I want to change the order of the string inside the array (not the order of the string**s**), but this isn't accepted. Any ideas?

```
public void invert() {

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0, k = array[i].length() - 1; j < k; j++, k--){
                char a = array[i].charAt(j);
                array[i].charAt(j) = array[k].charAt(k); //ERROR HERE
                array[i].charAt(k) = a;                  //AND HERE
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I'll leave here what I mean.
I have an array = `{"Hello", "Goodbye"}`
I want to change it to `{"olleH", "eybdooG"}`

Comment: Use `new StringBuilder.reverse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array[i].charAt(j) = array[k].charAt(k); //ERROR HERE
```

- `array[i].charAt(a)` returns a value not a variable. You are trying to assign a value to a value which doesn't make any sense.
- java `String` is immutable. You can't change it.
- Use `StringBuilder` which has [`setCharAt(int index,
           char ch);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29) function which is what you are probably wanting.

Answer (score 4):

Java string are immutable. You can't change them.

(But you can convert the string to a StringBuilder - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html - which is essentialy a mutable string, change the characters, and then convert the StrignBuilder back to String.)

Try this code (I haven't tested it, but I hope it works):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(array[i]);
        for(int j = 0, k = b.length() - 1; j < k; j++, k--){
            char a = b.charAt(j);
            b.setCharAt(j, array[k].charAt(k));
            b.setCharAt(k, a);                  
        }
        array[i] = b.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just one little thing, it was array[i].charAt(k). Was getting "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12" and couldn't figure out where hehe. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, then you can use just this: `b.setCharAt(j, b.charAt(k));`.

Answer (score 0):

try doing `new StringBuilder(array[i]).reverse().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is, to reverse letter with [StringBuilder.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method. Try,

```
 for(String str : array){
   System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this on every `String` in your array:

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(stringFromArray).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

you would have to create a substring.

array[i]= array[i].substring(0,j) + array[k].charAt(k) + array[i].substring(j+1);

This would do the required edit i beleive